# Get the string placing in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to know how to get the character place where the number is greater than 0:

- e.g. 0000134 result is 1
- e.g. 30001 result is 3
- e.g. 0002003 result is 2

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

In any database, you could use something like this:

```
select substring(cast(cast(col as int) as varchar(255)), 1, 1)
```

The idea is to convert to a number and back to a string -- that removes the leading zeros.

All these functions are available in all databases, although the names might be different.

Another method that doesn't require converting is:

```
select substring(replace(col, '0', ''), 1, 1)
```

There may be better ways in a particular database (which you haven't specified).

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL answer:

```
select substring(trim('0' from columnname) from 1 for 1) from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @val = '0002003'

SELECT LEFT(CAST(CAST(@val AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(10)),1)
```